# How can i select a number of objects from and array using Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Currently I have the following:

```
$scope.org = $.grep($scope.orgList, function (o) { return o.ServiceName === 
model.Org.ItemValue; })[0];
```

This will search orgList and extract only one value where the ItemValue is equal to model.Org.ItemValue

How can i do the following :
I have 2 lists

$scope.tempOrgList which has values of

```
  ItemValue = "Org1"
  ItemValue = "Org2"
  ItemValue = "Org8"
```

$scope.orgList has objects

```
  ServiceName = "Org1",  Name = "1"
  ServiceName = "Org2" , Name = "2"
  ServiceName = "Org3"  ,Name = "3"
  ServiceName = "Org4" , Name = "4"
  ServiceName = "Org5" , Name = "5"
  ServiceName = "Org6" , Name = "6"
  ServiceName = "Org7" , Name = "7"
  ServiceName = "Org8" , Name = "8"
  ServiceName = "Org9" , Name = "9"
  ServiceName = "Org10", Name = "10"
  ServiceName = "Org11", Name = "11"
  ServiceName = "Org12", Name = "12"
  ServiceName = "Org13", Name = "13"
  ServiceName = "Org14", Name = "14"
  ServiceName = "Org15", Name = "15"
  ServiceName = "Org16", Name = "16"
```

There are more fields for orgList but i have only shown 2 .

How can i only select the objects in orgList that have ServiceName equal to "Org1" and  "Org2" and "Org3" and put them into an array , so basically what ever is in

tempOrgList, I want to select those from orgList where  ServiceName in orglist is equal to the ItemValues in tempOrgList ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a combination of `array.filter` to get only elem that match a condition and `array.some` to get only item present in tempOrgList where service name equal ItemValue

```
var newArray = $scope.orgList.filter(oneOrg => $scope.tempOrgList.some(oneTempOrg => oneTempOrg.ItemValue === oneOrg.ServiceName));
```

Following you will find the js equivalent to see the reply result

```js
const tempOrgList = [
  { ItemValue: "Org1"},
  { ItemValue: "Org2"},
  { ItemValue: "Org8"}
]

  

const orgList = [  
  {ServiceName: "Org1",  Name: "1"},
  {ServiceName: "Org2" , Name: "2"},
  {ServiceName: "Org3"  ,Name: "3"},
  {ServiceName: "Org4" , Name: "4"},
  {ServiceName: "Org5" , Name: "5"},
  {ServiceName: "Org6" , Name: "6"},
  {ServiceName: "Org7" , Name: "7"},
  {ServiceName: "Org8" , Name: "8"},
  {ServiceName: "Org9" , Name: "9"},
  {ServiceName: "Org10", Name: "10"},
  {ServiceName: "Org11", Name: "11"},
  {ServiceName: "Org12", Name: "12"},
  {ServiceName: "Org13", Name: "13"},
  {ServiceName: "Org14", Name: "14"},
  {ServiceName: "Org15", Name: "15"},
  {ServiceName: "Org16", Name: "16"}
];

var newArray = orgList.filter(oneOrg => tempOrgList.some(oneTempOrg => oneTempOrg.ItemValue === oneOrg.ServiceName));

console.log(newArray);
```